# How to change bibliography name in report

Tags: bibliographies

I need to change my bibliography name to webography
but I don't know how ;

this is my  page of bibliography:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    
    \bibitem{maReference17}www.africmemoire.com/part.6-chapitre-iii-implementation-de-lapplication-949.html
    \bibitem{maReference18}www.medium.com/@sidibemouhamed/10-raisons-pour-lesquelles-jaime-expo-f19b6ecfe369
    \bibitem{maReference19}www.fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerAMC:~:text=PowerDesigner
    
    \end{thebibliography}
```

Any ideas !!!

btw:I'm not using file .bib

Comment: Did you see my MWE answer?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a MWE, as simple as possible:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Webography}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{maReference17}www.africmemoire.com/part.6-chapitre-iii-implementation-de-lapplication-949.html
    \bibitem{maReference18}www.medium.com/@sidibemouhamed/10-raisons-pour-lesquelles-jaime-expo-f19b6ecfe369
    \bibitem{maReference19}www.fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerAMC:~:text=PowerDesigner
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if you aren't, to use the BibLaTeX package, and then you can use `\bibname` or `\refname` to rename your bibliography as such:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Webography}
```